# Create Code that Directly Interfaces with X

Tags: linux, desktop

I am building a program for media centers - think like EmulationStation but with more than emulators, such as Kodi and Firefox support. It’s meant to launch various programs, not play the media itself. Obviously, the program will run on a Raspberry Pi. I feel that launching startx is overkill, as many programs won’t need it and it will slow the Pi down. But then, how do I create a GUI? I want the program to have a modern feel, and be user friendly enough anyone could figure it out. What is the easiest/best way to do show graphics onscreen? Note that I can use most languages, but I have no idea how to show graphics outside of PyGame.

Comment: *What is the easiest/best way to do this?* probably the way you're doing it now is the best ... since you are already doing it (*I **am** building*)

Comment: Welcome. Could you [edit] to explain which specific bit you're unsure with? Explaining how to create a whole media centre would be too much to ask from this site, but a more specific problem might be answerable.

Comment: @JaromandaX By that I mean I’m looking for how to do it, no real code exists. What I’ve seen is “use X” which I would do, but this isn’t its purpose, and besides, no one will explain how to do it.

Comment: @Aurora0001 I edited to include more detail, I simply need a way to draw to the screen. The program would launch the media center itself.